# Add moment to angular 2 (angular cli)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have followed the guid lines at the cli [github page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation). But I am unable to make it work in my app.
Here is what I did:

1. installed moment: `npm install moment --save`
2. installed moment ts typings: `npm install @types/moment --save`
3. imported moment in one of my components: `import * as moment from 'moment';`

I am getting the following error:
[image: img]

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, I just realised that you have done the same thing as my answer and still gets this error. If yes, what is your `webpack` version that you're running?

Comment: Steps to add Moment.js to Angular-CLI https://medium.com/@jek.bao.choo/steps-to-add-moment-js-to-angular-cli-f9ab28e48bf0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To install third party library in the newest version of `angular-cli` is just made simpler. (The webpack version, not systemjs one).

Go to your **angular-cli.json** on your project root and configure it like,

```
{
  ...
  "apps": [
     ...
     "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"
     ]
     ...
  ]
  ...
}
```

Then finally, in your **any.component.ts** you can import it like this,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
    selector: '[id=home]',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit () {
        console.log('today is', moment());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added the scripts tag as you suggested (take a look: http://prntscr.com/cnv1xn) but still I have the same problem

Comment: Modifying the angular cli json file and doing an ecma script import statement will load that lib twice. see this page for details https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts#using-global-libraries-inside-your-app

Comment: @Ronnel What do you expect? This answer is 1 year old. But, that's a have to look at, even for this pluginless library. It's crazy they let us to import it from global into ts like that but letting such a downside uncovered. I'll give it a play and update soon. Thanks

Comment: @choz Just thought of posting that as a comment so others looking into the same knows..

Comment: I want to change date formate dynamic in moment angular 4 please suggest me best way

Answer (score 2):

This thread is a little old but this is what I needed. Moment now comes with a type definition file and `@types/moment` is now deprecated in favor of this new file.  In order to have moment work with other libraries which extend type definitions from moment like [fullcallendar](https://fullcalendar.io/), you'll also need to override the default module resolution in your **tsconfig.app.json**

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
        "moment": [
          "../node_modules/moment/moment.d.ts", 
          "../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"
        ]
    },
},
```

You'll also want to update your **angular.json** build section to include moment:

```
 "build": {
      ...,
      "options": {
        ...
        "scripts": [ "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js"]
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include to include moment using the CommonJS syntax, rather than import.  Try the following:

```
let moment = require('moment');
```

This is because moment is not as ES6 module yet, and as such won't work with the newer `import` syntax.

**UPDATE:**

When I think about it, I have only used this approach in my unit tests.  Using it in your app may not work the same way because this approach uses node's `require`, which can't be used client side.

However, when using Moment in your components, you can use [angular2-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment).  Full setup instructions can be found on the GitHub page, but the usage looks like this:

```
<div>today is {{ Date.now() | amDateFormat:'LL' }}</div>
```

There are a few other pipes you can use, which are all documented on the GitHub page.

**UPDATE 2:**

As of v2.10.0, Moment now supports the ES6 syntax, so you should be able to use any ES6 `import` syntax instead of `require`.

Comment: great answer @Maloric. Works for me. Perfect. I have a question to clarify further. What is the difference between using let moment = require('moment') vs import * as moment from 'moment'? In terms of performance. https://medium.com/@jek.bao.choo/steps-to-add-moment-js-to-angular-cli-f9ab28e48bf0#.z9v3lhb6q

Comment: I used require because at the time moment was not built for ES6 (i.e. it didn't use export).  I believe it was ported to ES6 in 2.10.0, so you should be able to use import.  That way Typescript helpers in your IDE of choice should pick up autocomplete suggestions.  I don't know if there is a significant difference in performance, though.

Answer (score 1):

I had to update my cli version:

`npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm cache clear 
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Comment: Newest versions should be:
    npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
    npm cache clear
    npm install -g @angular/cli